# XMLRPC and Underscored custom fields

Tags: xml-rpc, featured-post, automation

I was creating my application to automate all of my blogs from my desktop.
Target, I'll post blog. That's all.
I used **XMLRPC** service, as you know "xmlrpc.php".

I built many of parts, near to done... But stucked at custom fields which are starting with (_) an underscore.
I would like to save as "_thumbnail_id" => (int)number. Nothing happened.

But when I tried "thumbnail_id" or something like that without starting with underscore. It's ok. Working well but start with underscore...

I need it for determine featured image of post. Without that tag; I couldn't. And I don't know alternatives.

I find this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-change-protected-params-xmlrpc
But not solving my problem. I don't want to change wordpress files. If I have to, I can write a small script without RPC.

Any help will be FANTASTIC!

Answer (score 3):

### Playing with XML-RPC and underscored custom fields:

Let's say we want to set the featured image to a given post with `$remote_post_id`.

We want it to be the attachment with ID equal to `300`, so we want `_thumbnail_id` to be `300`.

Here are three methods how one could achieve that:

### Method #1 - Using `post_thumbnail`

It's possible to update/add the featured image with the `post_thumbnail` parameter:

```
$result = $client->query( 
    'wp.editPost', 
    array(
        $blog_id,
        $username,
        $password,
        $remote_post_id,
        $post_data = array(
            'post_thumbnail' => '300',
        ),
    ) 
);
```

as can be seen [here in the `wp_xmlrpc_server`][1] class.

### Method #2 - Using `custom_fields` with `meta_id`

If we want to update a custom field of a post, we must know it's database `meta_id` value.

But how do we know the `meta_id`?

The custom fields are actually included by default, when we fetch a post with:

```
$result = $client->query( 
    'wp.getPost', 
    array(
        $blog_id,
        $username,
        $password,
        $remote_post_id,
    ) 
);
```

If the post has a featured post thumbnail, then the above result will contain this part:

```
<member>
    <name>custom_fields</name>
    <value>
        <array>
            <data>
                <value>
                    <struct>
                        <member>
                            <name>id</name>
                            <value>
                                <string>560</string>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>key</name>
                            <value>
                                <string>_thumbnail_id</string>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>value</name>
                            <value>
                                <string>200</string>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                    </struct>
                </value>
            </data>
        </array>
    </value>
 </member>
```

where the `meta_id` is for example `560` and the old `meta_value` is `200`.

Now we can update the meta value of `_thumbnail_id` with our new value:

```
$result = $client->query( 
    'wp.editPost', 
    array(
        $blog_id,
        $username,
        $password,
        $remote_post_id,
        $post_data = array(
            'custom_fields' => array( 
                array( 
                    'id'    => '560', 
                    'key'   => '_thumbnail_id', 
                    'value' => 300 
                )
            ),
        ),
    ) 
);
```

Notice that if we skip the `meta_id` part, we would only run `add_post_meta()`, instead of the [`update_metadata_by_mid()`][2] that was
introduced in [this trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17850#comment:28). We must also have the  *edit_post_meta* capability.

But this is not the whole story, because meta keys that begin with underscore (_) are *protected*.

We can fix that by using the [`register_meta()`][3] function on the remote site.

For example:

```
/**
 * Unprotect the _thumbnail_id meta key to allow updates via XML-RPC 
 * We need to set this up on the remote site.
 */

add_action( 'init', function() {
        register_meta( 'post', '_thumbnail_id', 'absint', '__return_true' );
});
```

to unprotect the `_thumbnail_id` meta key. I first tried the `intval` as a sanitization callback but that didn't work.

We could use a similar setup for other protected meta keys.

### Method #3 Using a custom XML-RPC method.

As @MarkKaplun mentioned in his answer, we could extend the XML-RPC setup to our needs. We could for example use the `xmlrpc_methods` filter to add our own method.

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) provides more information on that matter.

### References:

Here are some links that helped me while testing this:

- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php
- [XML RPC @Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)
- [Trac ticket #17850 @wp.org](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17850)
- [`update_metadata_by_mid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata_by_mid/)
- [Automattics "syndication" repo @GitHub: `class-syndication-wp-xmlrpc-client.php`](https://github.com/Automattic/syndication/blob/master/includes/class-syndication-wp-xmlrpc-client.php)
- [Content Type Standards @GitHub](https://github.com/justintadlock/content-type-standards/issues/5) (props @kaiser) - and more specifically [this issue](https://github.com/justintadlock/content-type-standards/issues/24), which explains the use case for `register_meta()` a bit more in detail, in the same repo.

Comment: Have you tested that? Would be nice to see better docs than those in Codex about that (highly unnoticed function).

Comment: I haven't test it yet, but I will try it out when I've the change. I wonder if @ErçinDedeoğlu had any success with the problem?

Comment: Some more info about it on an issue at [Justin Tadlocks](https://github.com/justintadlock/content-type-standards/issues/5) content standard GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did some testing and played around with this some more. @kaiser

Comment: n/p. I did some too - [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/18e1e497b85f712c8e32) was my test base (as mu-plugin). Even if I have it in there, I recommend _not_ adding sanitization callback to `register_meta()`. The `sanitze_{type}_meta_{key}` filter is much better and when you add a callback, the filter will get added twice. And that means that every callback runs twice. That could be devastating on callbacks that actually reduce data _per run_. You don't want that.

Comment: ok thanks, will check it out when I've gotten some sleep ;-)

Answer (score 1):

_Underscored meta data is defined to be data which is internal to the software and not directly changed by a user. This is probably why you can't change it via XMLRPC.

If you need this kind of functionality you can write a small plugin that extends the set of data you can change with XMLRPC.

But Since you question is specifically about featured images you should look for an api that lets you associate an attachment as a featured images. Fast google didn't epose any documentation for that but seems like people have done it successfully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355922/set-featured-image-for-wordpress-post-via-xml-rpc.